# How to change cursor image in ExtJS 4.1

Tags: extjs, cursor, extjs4

In ExtJS 4.0.2a I could change the cursor image over a grid using:

```
body.setStyle('cursor','move');
```

This doesn't seem to work in 4.0.7 or 4.1. I don't get any css error but it does give an unnatural lag at the point where the change should occur. Maybe it gets overridden?

**UPDATE:**

I am trying to run this from a grid `onitemmousedown` event. I found that the `GridView` gets a class ".x-unselectable" to make grid text unselectable (which I want). However in ExtJS 4.0.7 and 4.1 this ".x-unselectable" class has a `cursor: default` setting which gets inherited by all rows and cells of the grid and which overrides any other style attributes I apply to the cursor. It didn't have this in 4.0.2a.

If I force the gridview cursor style using `!important` the cursor only changes when I get it exactly on top of the 1px line in between two rows because the row still inherits the cursor setting. I suppose I could override the cursor style for all rows *and then* all cells using this same method but it seems like there should be some cleaner extjs method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any particular reason not to just use CSS?

```
<style>
.MyTarget{
   cursor: pointer;
}

/*override the panel header cursor */
.x-form-field {
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<div class="MyTarget">The cursor will be a pointer over the body here</div>

// Some Ext to create a panel - the panel header will have the new cursor declared in the CSS
```

Comment: I needed it to change on a mouse down event specifically. I tried using regular css with the extjs method body.addCls('class-name...'); And even though I see the class applied in firebug the cursor doesn't change...

Comment: As per the suggestion from Eric, have you also tried adding !important to your declaration?  
`Ext.getBody().setStyle("cursor", "move !important");`
To keep the grid from restyling the cursor?

Comment: I managed to override it on the gridview using `!important` unfortunately each row of the grid inherits the class `.x-unselectable` which sets `cursor: default` it does this to make text unselectable (which I want) but it means the cursor only changes when I get it exactly on top of the 1px line in between two rows... I suppose I could try overriding the cursor style for all rows and then all cells using this same method but it seems like there should be something cleaner as part of extjs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `body` is referring directly to the DOM element for the body. Have you tried

```
Ext.getBody().setStyle("cursor", "move");
```

That will wrap the body as an `Ext.Element` and give you all the nice methods. If that doesn't work, I suggest opening up a debugger and stepping into the setStyle function to see if anything weird is going on, or putting a watch on `body.style.cursor`.

Comment: I have body defined as Ext.getBody() not DOM element. The watch shows that the cursor _is_ changed to "move". It must get overridden in the grid or somewhere below it in versions beyond 4.0.2. Maybe there is some way to disable the override.