# ExtJS Swap panels as items list

Tags: extjs6-classic

I need to swap panels in a list. I've tried to reorder rows in a grid but I need to put a little more informations in the item so a panel will be nicely to show.

Must be the classic drag icon (four arrows) like here http://examples1.ext.net/#/DragDrop/Panel/Swap_Dropable_Panel/

This example is very close that I want. I need only vertical swap like this one http://tof2k.com/ext/sortable/ ( this could be just what I need but seems it don't use ExtJS themes and I don't know if I can put more information inside the items - and it is a little ugly too).

Some ideas?

Comment: Hold on... I'll try this: http://www.vinylfox.com/getting-started-with-grid-drag-drop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using a grid with a templatecolumn and drag and drop resolve your issue.

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1i7l

Also, you can use CSS to change row.

```
.customRow .x-grid-cell-inner {
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   background-color: yellow;       
}
```

Remove de comment

> //cls: 'customRow'

on fiddle (line 58).

Comment: Yes! Just what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Oops... forgot the `classic drag icon (four arrows)`... how can I do it? Bonus: the OnDrop event...

Comment: Maybe this helps to find a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646507/how-to-change-cursor-using-extjs  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116097/how-to-change-cursor-image-in-extjs-4-1

Comment: A little add to the column definition: `cellWrap: true,` will wrap long texts.

Comment: What was your solution to the cursor?

Comment: Well... I gave up for now. It is fine to me until I find more time to play with (or my client complains).